# Jquery: Getting certain url path using window.location

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, window.location

Our url pathname is

```
www.nicadpower.com/index.com
```

but we only want to get the pathname after *www.nicadpower.com* which is

```
index.com
```

how can we get index.com using window.location and jquery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want

```
window.location.pathname
```

This would give you /index.com

To get rid of the leading /, you could simply use substring:

```
window.location.pathname.substring(1);
```

Comment: console.log(window.location.pathname.substring(1));

putting this one on my js says that is getting www.nicadpower.com/index.php

Comment: thanks ord! now is works good. i just added more integer on the substring. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another trick that you can use.
You can split the pathname parts using split method, like that:

If you have the url: `www.nicadpower.com/posts/2012`

Using: `window.location.pathname.split('/')`

You'll Give: `["", "posts", "2012"]`